# Showing that any two ideals of a commutative ring are hold in ring homomorphism as follow

Tags: ideals, ring-homomorphism

Sorry about my english as in the title above.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I, J$ are ideals of $R$. Let $f:R \to R'$ be a ring homomorphism. Show that $f(I+J) = f(I) + f(J)$ and $f(IJ) = f(I)f(J)$.

My attempt: (**Edited**)

First, we'll show that $f(I+J) = f(I) + f(J)$.

For left to the right, let $x,y\in f(I+J)$, that's $x = f(a+b)$ and $y=f(c+d)$ for $a,c \in I$ and $b,d \in J$.
Now, we have
\begin{align*}
x+y = f(a+b) + f(c+d) &= f((a+c)+(b+d))
\\
&= f(a+c) + f(b+d) \\
&\in f(I) + f(J)
\end{align*}

Next, for right to the left, let $s\in I, t\in J$ such that $f(s) + f(t) \in f(I) + f(J)$. So, $f(s) + f(t) = f(s+t) \in f(I+J)$.

Hence, $f(I+J) = f(I) + f(J)$.

Now, we'll prove the rest.

For left to the right, let $x \in f(IJ)$, that's $x = f(a_1b_1+a_2b_2+\dots a_nb_n)$ where $a_i \in I, b_i \in J, i=1,2,\dots,n$.
Then,
\begin{align*}
x = f(a_1b_1+a_2b_2+\dots a_nb_n) &= f(a_1b_1) + f(a_2b_2) + \dots f(a_nb_n) \\
&= f(a_1)f(b_1) + f(a_2)f(b_2) + \dots + f(a_n)f(b_n) \\
&\in f(I)f(J)
\end{align*}

For right to the left, let $y \in f(I)f(J)$, that's $y=\sum_{p=1}^n f(a_p)f(b_p)$.
Then,
\begin{align*}
y = f(a_1)f(b_1) + f(a_2)f(b_2) + \dots + f(a_n)f(b_n) &= f(a_1b_1) + f(a_2b_2) + \dots + f(a_nb_n) \\
&= f(a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + \dots + a_nb_n) \\
&\in f(IJ)
\end{align*}

Hence, $f(IJ) = f(I)f(J)$.

Is above true? Please give me some corrections. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be correct, except the $f(I + J) \subset f(I) + f(J)$. Here, you seem to overcomplicate, while using the same idea as in the other inclusions suffices.

Comment: @EmielLanckriet What do you mean "overcomplicate"?

Comment: You introduce $x$ and $y$ in $f(I + J)$ instead of just one element of $f(I + J)$.

Comment: @EmielLanckriet What's about now?

Comment: Yeah, I notice the spelling mistake, but my problem is that you could have just used $x$ only. I'll try to explain in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The proof looks OK,
but for the inclusion $f(I+J) \subset f(I) + f(J)$ isn't this sufficient?
Take $x \in f(I + J)$, then $$ \exists a \in I, b \in J: x = f(a + b). $$
$f$ is a homomorphism, so $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$. This means that $x = f(a) + f(b) \in f(I) + f(J)$.
This way you also don't have to motivate that $x + y$ represent an arbitrary element of $f(I+J)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for correction and the answer.

Comment: Note, technically what you wrote is not really wrong, it's just not needed.

Comment: Yes, I know it.

Comment: I've been intimidated about the word "homomorphism", so that I must take two elements in the ring.